# Создание атрибута класса изменяемого (mutable) типа со значением по-умолчанию с помощью dataclasses.make_dataclass()

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataclass

Коллеги, изучаю `dataclasses` и наткнулся на момент, который не могу понять/реализовать.

**Общая информация.**

В `dataclasses` невозможно напрямую, без применения объектов самой библиотеки `dataclasses` создать атрибут класса изменяемого типа. Зачем это сделано описано в [доке](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) и еще [вот нашел](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53632152/why-cant-dataclasses-have-mutable-defaults-in-their-class-attributes-declaratio), коллеги подробно обсуждают этот вопрос. Но с помощью методов `dataclasses` это все же можно сделать.

Вот канонический пример, как делать нельзя:

```
@dataclass
class Foo:
    bar: list = []
```

Тут случится `ValueError`

А вот так можно (нужно!):

```
@dataclass
class Foo:
    bar: list = field(default_factory=list)
```

В этом случае создается атрибут типа `List`, но значение по-умолчанию не присваивается. Дока не описывает как присвоить дефолтное значение изменяемого типа сразу при определение класса, но коллеги подсказывают:

```
@dataclass
class Foo:
    bar: list = field(default_factory=lambda: [1, 2, 3])
```

**Проблема.**

В `dataclasses` существует метод `.make_dataclass()`, который определяет датакласс "налету", его не надо заранее определять. Как он работает мне, в общем, тоже понятно, но вот именно с вопросом присвоения дефолтного значения переменной изменяемого типа - затык. По разному пытался, получаю исключения разных типов.

Например:

```
from dataclasses import make_dataclass, field
Config = make_dataclass('Config', [('x', field(default_factory=lambda: [1,2,3]))])
config = Config()
print(config.x)
```

На моменте создания экземпляра `config = Config()` поднимается исключение:

> TypeError: Config.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

То есть, атрибут мы создали, но значение не присвоили. Ровно тоже самое происходит если убрать `lambda`: класс создается без ошибок, атрибут создается, но дефолтное значение игнорируется.

**Вопрос**

Как создать `dataclass` с помощью метода `.make_dataclass()` с атрибутом изменяемого типа, которому сразу присвоится значение по-умолчанию. Возможно ли это в принципе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не указали тип

```
from dataclasses import make_dataclass, field
import typing

Config = make_dataclass('Config', [('x', typing.Any,field(default_factory=lambda: [1,2,3]))])
config = Config()
print(config.x)
```

Дополнительно. [Здесь](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ec23e90082ffdedc7f0bdd2dfadfc4983ddc0712/Lib/dataclasses.py#L1452C77-L1452C77) приведена реализация `def make_dataclass()`, где можно увидеть, в частности, как именно разбирается аргумент `fields` в зависимости от количества значений в каждом кортеже, которых может быть от 1 до 3.

Наблюдение. Вместо `typing.Any` можно использовать `None`. Работают также любые типы и константы различных типов :)

Comment: Исчерпывающе, благодарю! То есть, я тут поэксперементировал и получается, что на месте типа может быть написана почти (абсолютно(?)) любая ерунда не противоречащая синтаксису и метод отработает как ожидается. Оригинально :)

Comment: ...то есть, до меня дошло, что в моем, неработающем примере, метод воспринимал мою конструкцию `field(default_factory=lambda: [1,2,3])` как тип. Никаких ошибок, все отрабатыват, но делает совсем не то, что хочется. Ясно-понятно :)

Comment: ... почитал реализацию `.make_dataclass`, по ссылке, которую Вы прислали (спасибо!). Там, оказывается (но, в общем, логично) на втором месте в кортеже ожидается не тип, а аннотация. Поэтому она и может быть чем угодно. Еще раз благодарю за ценные наводки!